# Is it possible to derive an implementation for `Ord` for this tree type? And if not, why?

Tags: haskell

I have defined the following very generic tree type:

```
data YTree f g a = YNode (f a (g (YTree f g a)))
```

I have defined a functor instance as follows (to demonstrate that it is possible to work with):

```
instance (Bifunctor f, Functor g) => Functor (YTree f g) where
    fmap f (YNode m) = YNode $ bimap f (fmap (fmap f)) m
```

I then successfully derived some instances (using `StandaloneDeriving`, `ExplicitForAll` and `QuantifiedConstraints`):

```
deriving instance (Show a, forall x y. (Show x, Show y) => Show (f x y), forall z. Show z => Show (g z)) => Show (YTree f g a)
deriving instance (Read a, forall x y. (Read x, Read y) => Read (f x y), forall z. Read z => Read (g z)) => Read (YTree f g a)
deriving instance (Eq a, forall x y. (Eq x, Eq y) => Eq (f x y), forall z. Eq z => Eq (g z)) => Eq (YTree f g a)
```

However, the following `deriving instance` clause throws an error when included:

```
deriving instance (Ord a, forall x y. (Ord x, Ord y) => Ord (f x y), forall z. Ord z => Ord (g z)) => Ord (YTree f g a)
```

Namely,

```
Data\Tree\Generalized.hs:32:1: error:
    * Could not deduce (Ord z)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: (Ord a,
                         forall x y. (Ord x, Ord y) => Ord (f x y),
                         forall z. Ord z => Ord (g z))
        bound by the instance declaration
        at Data\Tree\Generalized.hs:32:1-119
      or from: Eq z
        bound by a quantified context at Data\Tree\Generalized.hs:1:1
      Possible fix: add (Ord z) to the context of a quantified context
    * In the instance declaration for `Ord (YTree f g a)'
   |
32 | deriving instance (Ord a, forall x y. (Ord x, Ord y) => Ord (f x y), forall z. Ord z => Ord (g z)) => Ord (YTree f g a)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

as well as another error.

As far as I can see, the implementation would simply be:

```
instance (Ord a, forall x y. (Ord x, Ord y) => Ord (f x y), forall z. Ord z => Ord (g z)) => Ord (YTree f g a) where
    compare (YNode x) (YNode y) = compare x y
```

This produces the same error, though.

Is it possible to derive this? Why doesn't it work currently? Is it even possible to implement? Am I dead wrong?

Comment: This is like, verbatim the motivating example for QuantifiedConstraints. You okay with restricting yourself to very new compiler versions?

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug through and through. The complaints about a type variable `z` when we should be instantiating `z ~ YTree f g a` seem very strange. Perhaps GHC's getting stuck; it wants `Ord (YTree f g a)`, finds the current instance to satisfy that want, but then is confused because it has to cough up evidence for the quantified contexts.

Comment: @Daniel_Wagner yes, I am okay with that. It's not something in production or anything that needs compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
deriving instance
  ( Ord a, forall x y. (Ord x, Ord y) => Ord (f x y), forall z. Ord z => Ord (g z)
  , Eq  a, forall x y. (Eq  x, Eq  y) => Eq  (f x y), forall z. Eq  z => Eq  (g z)
  ) => Ord (YTree f g a)
```

will compile but I don't know why we need `Eq` constraints.